# Python Requests Authentication

Tags: python-3.x, api, python-requests

I'm trying to interact with an API via Python3's Requests module but the authentication is not working . I am able to take the exact same url with the same username/password and use the API via my Firefox browser.

There are a few complications with the setup, so let me explain.

1. The device I'm trying to talk with uses https but I don't have access to the certs so I'm choosing not to verify. I'm able to interact with Requests with older models that only use http no problem.
2. The device is on a local network but my company's network utilizes proxies that interfere with communication to devices on a local network so I turn these off.

Here's an example of my code:

```
session = requests.Session() 
auth = ('username', 'password')
session.auth = auth 
s.trust_env = False # remove proxies (see 2 above)
response = session.get(
      url='https://mylocalurl/api/',
      params={'apikey' : 'myapikey',
                'req' : 'generalInfo'},
      verify=False # don't verify SSL cert (see 1 above)
)
```

My first thought was that I had to specify the encoding of the credentials sent since I'm able to use those in my browser. I've tried doing `auth = (b'username', b'password')` with no luck. I looked at the `response.content` and found `b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>\n` in the first line so I tried specifying that by `auth = ('username'.encode('iso-8859-1'), 'password'.encode('iso-8859-1'))` but still no luck.

The questions I have are:

- The API's server is LightTPD, is there something particular with authenticating with this server via Python that I'm missing?
- Do I have to verify my SSL cert to authenticate? Wouldn't make sense but I'm asking anyway.
- Is there any more information I could gleam from the 401 response that could help me determine how to send the credentials in a way the server will accept?

Comment: Do you have documentation on the API you're trying to access? Often times you need to send the auth details as a request header. The Session.auth attribute sets http basic authentication credentials which may not be what your API is using.

Comment: @lvrf I do have the documentation. Unfortunately it's not on the web so I can't share. Is there a good example of this you could point me to so I could try it out?

Comment: For example to use the [Digital Ocean API](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/api/example-usage/) you need to provide an HTTP header such as "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN". It's hard for me to say that is the problem though without documentation fir your specific system. Does your documentation show you equivalent curl commands?

Comment: Here's a sample URL:  https://address/scr/download_api.pl?uid=uid&req=C&grp=1&chn=2&sd=2019-01-24&ed=2019-01-
 25&dsl=N&fmt=csv 
The uid is essentially a token. The other parameters are all optional.